# Difference between fork(3) and fork(2)

Tags: c, linux, fork, system-calls

I roughly read

http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork
and 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork

got confused.
can anybody briefly explain to me difference between fork(3) and fork(2)
thank you

Comment: section 2 of the man pages is system/kernel calls, section 3 is library calls. fork(2) is the kernel call, fork(3) is the posix library call, which internally would call fork(2) somewhere

Comment: The proper way to refer to man page belonging to section 2 or system call is `function_name(2)`, not `function_name2`. Others are similar.

Comment: Read the man pages [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) on http://man7.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fork(2) is the kernel call and fork(3) is the posix library call